# Connection loss to random websites on LAN

Tags: google-chrome, router, lan, dhcp, switch

I work in as an IT manager in an office where there are 10+ computers. What my question is that, a particular computer has a connection to some websites. The network setup is a LAN connected to a router for internet access via a switch. The router is A Prolink 4 port standard router.

I switched off the DHCP and gave each PC with IP address. All of the other computers have loss-less internet access, but one PC has a problem with some websites. I'ts not with the websites since, google, yahoo are in the list.

I tried to ping the respective websites and the ping command successfully completed. but when I try to connect with a browser, it returns a "No Data Received" error. Tried with chrome & firefox and both gives the same error.

Further more, there is no firewall blocking these websites and I have checked both the windows firewall as well as the router firewall.

Please help me to find the error in my network.

Thank you.

[image: This is the network diagram drawn using cisco packet tracer.]

Comment: I can only suggest a process of elimintaion. Comapre the IP settings in Control Panel (if we are talking about windows, else do the similar for Linux/Mac). Swap network cards. Connect the PC in the phyiscal place of one that is ok, in case it is just the cable. As last resort, back-up the PC and either fresh install or clone a PC with no problems onto it ...  Something is different ... reaplce things until it starts working and you will find what it is

Comment: Is there an external firewall?

Comment: there is no external firewall Sam. I've considered a fresh install but, it's too much work. with the software we use in our company! any other ways I can diagnose this error!

Comment: change DNS IP address of that particular machine apart with the one given by your ISP and then check websites. When you do traceroute to the website, what you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intermittent failure on one computer in a network:

IP address conflict.  Are there two devices on your network using the same IP address?  Specifically is the IP address to the computer in question used anywhere else in the network?  Did you check and make sure the subnet mask is correct?

Next, is there a proxy configured or involved?

Are there any services running on the computer in question?  Any software that would try and use the same port that any web browser would use?

Have you checked to see if there is any malware using ports?

This is a good start.

Comment: There is no IP conflict. earlier there was one ip conflict and windows automatically detected the conflict and I changed it. There is no proxy involved in the network. this is a simple LAN network. The most used program is auto cad 2012. I don't think it uses the same port as the browser! The virus guard is a kaspersky and I checked for malware as well as kaspersky interferences. there was no such things and, i can access some other websites while some of them return the error "No data received".

Comment: "detected the conflict and I changed it"

I've had cases where this didn't permanently correct the conflict and I had to go in by hand and set it correctly.  Did you check the subnet mask?

At this point you should edit your question and include a network diagram from the cloud in.

Have you checked the ethernet cable path (is it crossing over or through a noise source)?

Is the ethernet port on the computer and on the switch or router its connected to known good (what happens when a different computer on the network uses the same port on the router or switch)?

Comment: Also, what plugins do you have on your browsers or are they all stock browsers?  Do you have the same problem on this computer using other network services (FTP, SSH, email)?

Comment: The reason I ask for the network diagram is that I've been told "it's just a simple network" then found out there are all kinds of devices in line in front of the "simple network" connection to the ISP.  If I'm going to troubleshoot your network I need to know every device from the connection the ISP provides to the computer in question.  Include IP addresses, device names, and services provided (i.e. DHCP server, is it turned on, is it handing out IP addresses, what range, what subnet mask).  Also include the ipconfig or ifconfig output from the computer in question.

Comment: I've added the network diagram with the given IP addresses to each PC.

Comment: @Dimal - Thanks for the diagram, what about all the questions I asked?

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem :

1. Open Kaspersky interface
2. go to `Settings > Anti-Virus Protection > Firewall > Network Packet Rules`
3. From here Allow all blocked connections which are using `UDP, TCP, Incoming ICMP & ICMPv6`
4. Save and restart your PC